# Xen hypervisor: not booting

Tags: ubuntu, xen

So I'm new to the xen hypervisor and I'm trying to install it on a ubuntu 16.04 VM on my computer.

I've done the following

```
sudo apt-get install xen-hypervisor-amd64

sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_DEFAULT=.*+/GRUB_DEFAULT="Xen 4.1-amd64"/' /etc/default/grub

sudo update-grub

sudo sed -i 's/TOOLSTACK=.*+/TOOLSTACK="xm"/' /etc/default/xen

sudo reboot
```

when it starts back up it scrolls through some lines of code showing that it's booting xen but then it goes to a black unresponsive screen

[here is what i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeqGh.png)

I'm not sure how to solve this issue but any advice is welcome!!!!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't support xen. I installed a Ubuntu 12.04.4 VM and it now works

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 no need to update the grub and it does by default.

Just run this command given below:

```
sudo apt-get install xen-hypervisor-amd64

sudo reboot
```

While the reboot your system it will show you the xen-hypervisor version.
And loading a initial ramdisk, and then start Ubuntu.

When successfully run the Ubuntu 16.04 and run this command:

```
xl list (domain-0),xl info (xen-information)
```